# FILETIME to/from ISO 8601 with Win32 API. Getting DST right?

Tags: c++, winapi, dst, iso8601, filetime

Wrote something in .NET; it works well. Now I am trying to rewrite it as a shell extension with the Win32 API. Ultimately I want to convert `FILETIME`s to and from ISO-8601 strings. This is doable without fuss, using `GetTimeZoneInformation` and `FileTimeToSystemTime` and `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime` and `StringCchPrintf` to assemble the members of the `SYSTEMTIME` and `TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` structs into a string.

The problem, as usual when working with date/times, is Daylight Saving Time. Using `GetTimeZoneInformation` tells me the UTC offset that's in effect *now*. Using .NET's `DateTime.ToString("o")` takes into account the daylight saving time *at the time represented in the DateTime*.

Example for the same `FILETIME`:
Output of `ToString("o")`: 2017-06-21T12:00:00.0000000-05:00
Output of chained APIs: 2017-06-21T12:00:00-06:00

The UTC offset is wrong coming from the chained API calls. How does .NET's `DateTime` do it? How do we replicate that in Win32? Is there something like `GetTimeZoneInformationForYear`, but instead of for a year, for a moment in local time?

Comment: MS-Windows has a timezone database in the registry `\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones` used by the .NET `TimeZoneInfo Class`.  This class uses the `ICU Library` on Linux see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo?view=net-5.0 the paragraph just above __Properties__

Comment: You can use `GetTimeZoneInformationForYear`, but then you need to apply the `DaylightBias` if the date is in the DST period.  The rules for figuring that out are a bit complex, as the `StandardDate` and `DaylightDate` are usually not specific dates but rather represent the recurrence rule in effect (i.e., the second Sunday of March, etc.).  Also they may be in opposite order than expected, for DST in the Southern hemisphere.

Comment: Also, do you *need* to use Win32? If you can use UWP you might consider `Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter` or `Windows.Globalization.Calendar`.  Or if you can use ICU, you can use `udat_format` or `udat_formatCalendar`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First, I use [`DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/ns-timezoneapi-dynamic_time_zone_information) structure and [`GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-getdynamictimezoneinformation)

`DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` and `TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` also has a `DaylightBias` member:

> The bias value to be used during local time translations that occur
> during daylight saving time. This member is ignored if a value for the
> DaylightDate member is not supplied.
>
> This value is added to the value of the Bias member to form the bias
> used during daylight saving time. In most time zones, the value of
> this member is –60.

So, if the date is in daylight saving time, you need to add this `DaylightBias` to `Bias`.
In addition, you can determine whether the current date is daylight saving time according to the description in `DaylightDate`:

> To select the correct day in the month, set the wYear member to zero,
> the wHour and wMinute members to the transition time, the wDayOfWeek
> member to the appropriate weekday, and the wDay member to indicate the
> occurrence of the day of the week within the month (1 to 5, where 5
> indicates the final occurrence during the month if that day of the
> week does not occur 5 times).
>
> If the wYear member is not zero, the transition date is absolute; it
> will only occur one time. Otherwise, it is a relative date that occurs
> yearly.